# How can I find a point where an osculating circle goes through a certain point?

Tags: osculating-circle

Given a point $P = (x_P, y_P)$ and a function $f(x)$, how can I find the set of all points $Q\in f$ such that the periphery of the osculating circle to $f$ in $Q$ goes through $P$? Is there a curve for which every osculating circle goes through $P$?

Comment: Check out this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle).

Comment: @Lays I couldn't find an answer to my question on the page you linked. Please note, that $P$ usually does not lay on $f$.